# "Almost dense" sequence tending to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does there exist an increasing sequence $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and, for all natural $d \ge 1$, the sequence contains all but finitely many members of the set
$$Q_d = \left \{ \frac{n}{d}: n \ge 1 \right \}?$$
It appears this is quite a strong condition to impose on an increasing sequence tending to infinity, but I'm having trouble assuming everything holds and deriving a contradiction.

Is there perhaps some way to helpfully bound the growth of $a_n$? For instance, knowing $\{ a_n \}$ contains almost every number $m/2^k$, for every fixed $k$, would seem to constrain the growth a lot (to be almost like that of a geometric series?)

If $a_n$ exists, it will have to contain some element $a/b$ in lowest terms for every natural number $b$. To derive a contradiction, it would suffice to prove $a_n$ must have an accumulation point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the sequence

$$1, 1+\frac{1}{2}, 2, 2+\frac{1}{6}, 2+\frac{2}{6}, \dots, 2+\frac{5}{6}, 3, 3+\frac{1}{24}, \dots$$
where the progression goes like
$$\dots, k, k+\frac{1}{k!}, \dots, k+\frac{k!-1}{k!}, k+1, (k+1)+\frac{1}{(k+1)!}, \dots$$
It contains every $a/b$ for which $a \ge b^2$.

Of course this sequence grows very slowly.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in \mathbb N$ let $$S(n)=[n,n+1]\cap (\cup \{Q_d:d\leq n\}).$$ Let $S=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}S(n).$  Then each $Q_d$ \ $S$ is a subset of the finite set $Q_d\cap (0,d).$

Since $S\cap [n,n+1]=S(n)$ is finite for every $n$, we can enumerate $S$ in increasing order.